# Why am I always getting the wrong number of bulls in a cows and bulls game?

Tags: python, python-3.x

newbie to Python here. I am trying to code a cows and bulls game. But I can't seem to figure out why my code always returns 4 bulls and not the correct number of bulls.

Explanation of Cows and Bulls: Bulls - the number of correct digits regardless of position. Cows - the number of digits that would be correct if they were in the right position.

```
#Cows and Bulls game!
#User must correctly guess a computer-generated 4-Digit number.
#TASKS:
#1. Generate a random 4-digit number.
#2. Ask the user to enter the 4-Digit number.
#3. Compare the numbers obtained from the user and generated number.
#4. a correct digit at the correct place gives a cow.
#5. a correct digit at a wrong place gives a bull.
#6. the game continues until the user correctly guesses the number.

import random

cowsNbulls = {
    'cow': 0,
    'bull': 0,
  }

cpu_num = random.sample(range(0,9),4)
print(cpu_num)
num_tries = 0

correct_num = False
while not correct_num:
    user_input = int(input("Please choose a 4 digit number: \n"))
    user_num = [int(i) for i in str(user_input)]
    cowsNbulls['cow'] = 0
    cowsNbulls['bull'] = 0
    if user_num == cpu_num:
        correct_num = True
        print("Yay you got the number in {} tries!".format(num_tries))
    if user_num != cpu_num:
        for i in range(len(user_num)):
            if user_num[i] == cpu_num[i]:
                cowsNbulls['cow'] += 1
            if user_num[i] in cpu_num:
                cowsNbulls['bull'] += 1
        print(str(cowsNbulls['cow']), "Cows.", str(cowsNbulls['bull']), "Bulls")
    num_tries +=1
```

This is the code that it produces: (I also printed out the number to manually check against the number the computer generated.)

```
[0, 2, 4, 8]
Please choose a 4 digit number: 
8402
0 Cows. 4 Bulls
Please choose a 4 digit number: 
0000
1 Cows. 4 Bulls
Please choose a 4 digit number: 
9999
0 Cows. 0 Bulls
Please choose a 4 digit number: 
2222
1 Cows. 4 Bulls
Please choose a 4 digit number:
```

Comment: Since you don't remove the used digits, you end up double counting the bulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each iteration in your loop you are testing for both cow and bull (even if it already found a cow).

You'll want to change

```py
            if user_num[i] == cpu_num[i]:
                cowsNbulls['cow'] += 1
            if user_num[i] in cpu_num:
                cowsNbulls['bull'] += 1
```

to:

```py
            if user_num[i] == cpu_num[i]:
                cowsNbulls['cow'] += 1
            elif user_num[i] in cpu_num:
                cowsNbulls['bull'] += 1
```

This will only test for a bull if a cow was not found.

You could accomplish something similar by adding an additional check for bull with something like:
`if user_num[i] in cpu_num and user_num[i] != cpu_num[i]:`

But the first option is cleaner in my view.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But my aim is to test for both cows and bulls each round, not only test for bulls if a cow was not found.

Comment: Hi Lisa. You are iterating over each character (number) that the user submits. Each time you are asking: "is this character a cow OR is it a bull?" -- the two are mutually exclusive due to your definition of cow and bull. Technically there is a third "OR is it neither?" option that we will ignore for now. Your 2nd if statement checking for a bull should only be checked if the given character was NOT a cow (because a cow is a correct digit in the CORRECT place and a bull is a correct digit in the INCORRECT place). I believe if you make the change I suggest you will find your counts are correct.

Comment: Another way of saying the same thing above is that a cow and a bull are mutually exclusive, but your code currently allows a cow to be counted as a cow AND as a bull.